# Mysql does not show correct count on rows

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have this mysql installation that i am using to test some java program that has multiple threads.At first, i noted that some rows dissapeared and i thought it was because of this error `InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5745ms. The settings might not be optimal.`

I fixed that `SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=256;` by running that code and i also went to the optios page on the mysql workbench and edited and saved and also restarted my machine and the mysql server.

My java program has around 50 threads and from watching activity on the java jconsole program, i can tell that multiple threads are inserting data into the mysql table.

I am on windows and using heidisql and mysql workbench. When i check the number of rows on the command prompt, i get 32 rows

[image]

and a million plus rows when i look at the heidisql interface

[image]

I tend to believe that there are more than 1 million rows since i am using that many threads.

is there a reason why the table is showing 32 rows instead of a million plus rows?

Update

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're accessing the same schema ("database").

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that,maybe you can elaborate.

Comment: Are both zoorn tables in the same database? Could it be a transaction isolation level of repeatable read getting the same result? Is the estimate of `SELECT rows_changed
FROM information_schema.table_statistics WHERE  table_name='zoorn';` the same?

Comment: yes, both zoorn tables are in the same database. The estimate of the query above does not run,says no table_statistics in information schema.

Comment: My table, is quite big and i there seem to be consensus on table locking vs row locking when using big tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462643/why-is-table-level-locking-better-than-row-level-locking-for-large-tables but InnoDb has puzzled me today.

Comment: Something is not right when it takes more than 1 minute to count the supposedly grand total of 32 rows in an InnoDB table! Is this MySQL 5.7? What is the exact version number? Can you please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE hibernate.zoorn;`?

Comment: Yes, its mysql 5.7 community edition. I have since changed from innodb to myisam

Comment: Did you make sure to commit your transactions?

Comment: Nope i did not. I also thought that was the problem when inserting, i somehow should have wrapped in a transaction but i switched to myisam and inserted a million rows without any problems. I did check autocommit  though if it was on and i found the default is on.